# Terraform lock in gitlab ci pipeline

Tags: terraform, gitlab

I stop gitlab's pipeline during operation, and terraform state was locked afterwards.
So, I tried to unlock Terraform state in gitlab server, but it occured.

```
terraform
sh: terraform: command not found
```

So, I tried to implement the unlock process of terraform state in gitlab.yml file like below,

```yaml
before_script:
  - terraform --version
  - echo "Environment is ${ENV}"
  - aws configure set default.region $DEFAULT_REGION
  - terraform -chdir=terraform/${ENV} init
  - terraform force-unlock -force 6cf0e31a-a1f6-636a-9cb0-fec966d9e924
```

but, the result of gitlab pipeline is like below,

```
Failed to unlock state: LocalState not locked
```

Then I tried to find the process number of the previous pipeline pid like below,

```yaml
before_script:
  - terraform --version
  - echo "Environment is ${ENV}"
  - aws configure set default.region $DEFAULT_REGION
  - terraform -chdir=terraform/${ENV} init
  - ps aux | grep terraform
```

however, the result of gitlab pipeline is like below,

```
$ ps aux | grep terraform
  239 root      0:00 grep terraform
```

There is no information about `terraform apply`, I can not kill the process of the previous pipeline.

What is a good way to resolve this problem?

Comment: Looks like the previous pipeline was initialized with a remote backend?

Comment: @Paolo, Yes, the previous pipeline was initialized with a remote backend (gitlab-runner), and I stopped the pipeline during deploy(apply)